# React Native how to pass this.setState change to parent

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to React Native I am making a sample app where the user can login and register for a new account.

I have two React classes,

One is the main class index.ios.js and another class called register.js. In the index class I am saying if the variable register is true render the register screen.

In the class register.js I am trying to set the variable register to false using this.setState({register:false}) but it is not causing the re render of the parent (index.ios.js). Is the a super(state) method or something similar that I am missing ? I believe the parent state is not getting the values of the updated register variable.

Here are my classes:

Render inside index.ios.js:

```
render: function() {
    if(this.state.register) {
      return this.renderRegisterScreen();
    }
    else if (this.state.loggedIn) {
      return this.userLoggedIn();
    }
    else {
      return this.renderLoginScreen();
    }
  }
```

Register.js:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
} = React;

var Register = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.rafitoImage}>
              <Image source={require('./logo.png')}></Image>
              <Text style={styles.slogan}>Eliminate the need to wait!</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.bottomSection}>
              <View style={styles.username}>
                <View style={styles.inputBorder}>
                  <TextInput placeholder="Username..." style={styles.usernameInput} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputBorder}>
                  <TextInput password={true} placeholder="Password..." style={styles.usernameInput} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputBorder}>
                  <TextInput password={true} placeholder="Verify Password..." style={styles.usernameInput} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({verifyPassword: text})}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputBorder}>
                  <TextInput placeholder="Phone.." style={styles.usernameInput} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({phone: text})}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputBorder}>
                  <TextInput placeholder="Email.." style={styles.usernameInput} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}/>
                </View>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                  underlayColor='#f1c40f' onPress={this.register}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Register</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.signUp} onPress={this.resetToLogin}
                underlayColor='#ffffff'>
                <Text style={styles.signUpText}>Already A Member </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.copyright}>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
    },

    resetToLogin: function() {
        this.setState({
            register: false //I want this to re render the home screen with the variable register as false
        });
    }
});

    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex : 1
      },
      bottomSection: {
        flex: 5,
        flexDirection: 'row' 
      },
      button: {
            height: 36,
            backgroundColor: '#32c5d2',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            marginTop: 20
        },
      buttonText: {
            fontSize: 18,
            color: 'white',
            alignSelf: 'center'
      },
      signUpText: {
        color: '#3598dc'
      },
      signUp: {
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        marginTop: 10,
      },
      username: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 5
      },
      rafitoImage: {
        flex: 3,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      copyright: {
        alignItems: 'center'
      },
      usernameInput: {
            height: 36,
            marginTop: 10,
            marginBottom: 10,
            fontSize: 18,
            padding: 5
      },
      copyrightText: {
        color: '#cccccc',
        fontSize: 12
      },
      inputBorder: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#ececec'
      },
      slogan: {
        color: '#3598dc'
      }
    });

module.exports = Register;
```

**Attempt 1**

As per the answer I added this to my index.ios.js

```
renderRegisterScreen: function() {
    return (
      <Register login={this.login}/>
    )
  }
```

And I added this to my register.js

```
<TouchableHighlight style={styles.signUp} onPress={this.props.login}
                underlayColor='#ffffff'>
                <Text style={styles.signUpText}>Already A Member </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
```

But for some reason it does not even go to the register screen anymore, it executes the login function as soon as the register screen renders. What am I missing now ? Please advise.

Thanks

**Update**

It works when I pass down registered as a property but not when I do not. I would like to understand why if someone could post that.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can pass the function down to the child as props, then set the state of the parent from within the child that way.

Parent Component:

```
   var Parent = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            registered: false
        }
    },

  register(){
    console.log("logging in... ");
    this.setState({
        registered: true
    });

  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Child register={this.register.bind(this)} registered={this.state.registered} />
      {this.state.registered && <View style={{padding:10, backgroundColor:'white', marginTop:10}}>
                                    <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Congratulations, you are now registered!</Text>
                              </View>}
       </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Child Component:

```
var Child = React.createClass({

render: function() {
return(
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', paddingBottom:20, paddingTop:20 }}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{padding:20, color: 'white', backgroundColor: 'black'}} onPress={() => this.props.register() }>
 {this.props.registered ? <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>registered</Text> : <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>register</Text>}
        </TouchableHighlight>                     
    </View>
    ) 
  }
})
```

Comment: when you pass `register={this.register}` dont you have to bind register to the parent object? `register={this.register.bind(this)}`

Comment: @Macmee Not in this case, as we are only passing it as a prop as opposed to calling the actual function.

Comment: @NaderDabit if I try to use your code without the variable registered it never goes to the register screen. Do I need the registered variable ? I tried to do <Register login={this.login}/> and inside register.js I tried to do <TouchableHighlight style={styles.signUp} onPress={this.resetToLogin()}
                underlayColor='#ffffff'>
                <Text style={styles.signUpText}>Already A Member </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight> but for some reason it sets register: false on load of the screen

Comment: @NaderDabit your answer works when I pass down the register state as a property but not when I don't I would like to understand why that happens ?

Comment: Can you tell me how you are using the register state in the child view?

Comment: @Nader Dabit I updated the question with how I was trying to use it but I was failing to do so. Do you want to see the full code for both the js files ?

Comment: Is this okay/good practice to set state for a parent through a function provided to a child by prop? (Not saying it isn't, or is just learning react)

Answer (score 17):

Here is a more powerful solution. This will let the child component change any state variable in the parent.

Parent component:

```
render: function() {
    return (
       ...
        <Child setParentState={newState=>this.setState(newState)} />
       ...
    );
}
```

// Take note of the setState()

Child component:

```
this.props.setParentState({registered: true})
```

Comment: This should be the best answer

Comment: Agreed. The accepted answer would cause so much bloat in the main App.js for any middle+-sized app

Answer (score 2):

Why my attempt was failing was because I was using

```
onPress={this.props.login}
```

It should be

```
onPress={()=>this.props.login}
```

because of that mistake my onPress function would execute as soon as the button would render. I am not sure why that happens but I know what my mistake was.

Comment: I think `onPress={this.props.login.bind(this)}` might work also.

Answer (score 0):

Using `StackNavigator` I found a soultion leveraging `screenProps`. Here you can pass down functions and values to your routes. App global state is managed in `App`. `App` then passes in functions and/or state to `NavComponent` `screenProps`. Each child route in `StackNavigator` will then have access via `this.props.screenProps`

This solution is working well for now. Would love some feedback, or suggestions for improving this method

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.props.screenProps.awesome)}</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.screenProps.updateGlobalState("data")}
          title="Update parent State"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const NavComponent = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  // AllOthers: { screen: AllComponentsHereMayAccessScreenProps },
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      everythingIsAwesome: false,
    }
  }

  _updateGlobalState(payload) {
    console.log('updating global state: ', payload);
    this.setState({everythingIsAwesome: payload});
  }

  render() {
    return <NavComponent screenProps={{
      updateGlobalState: this._updateGlobalState.bind(this),
      awesome: this.state.everythingIsAwesome
    }} />;
  }
}
```