# loading/importing contents of Modal from another js (class) file in react-native

Tags: react-native

My modal displays an input form. I want to import contents of my Modal from another js file for keeping the main code shorter. I am actually able to import contents of my Modal from another class file by calling component's class name as jsx tag, but in this case I cannot pass state variables of main component to inner component of the modal or vice versa. And, I don't know if it is possible to receive data from the modal in this case. I know that I could use navigator with passProps, but I want to use just a modal for this purpose. For instance:

this is main Component:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this._showAddNewModal = this._showAddNewModal.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      addNewShow: false,
      mytext: '' // this should be updated through Modal.
    }
  }
  render(){
    return (
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this._showAddNewModal();}}>
          <Text> Show my modal </Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

      <Modal visible={this.state.addNewShow}>
        <MyModalContents />
      </Modal>
    );
  }
  _showAddNewModal(){
    this.setState({addNewShow: true});
  }
}
```

this is the component to be displayed in the modal:

```
class MyModalContents extends React.Component { // extends Modal?
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
    this.state = {mytext: ''}
  }
  render(){
    <View>
      <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({mytext: text})} />
    </View>
  }
}
```

I can't even close the modal because the state of 'addNewShow' is not accessible from MyModalContents. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props to a child component by cloning it with `React.cloneElement`. Here's an example of how you could use it with your modal:

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            mytext: '' // this should be updated through Modal.
        }

    }
    _showAddNewModal(){
        this.refs.modal.show();
    }
    render(){
        return <View>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._showAddNewModal}>
                <Text> Show my modal </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

            <Modal parent={this} ref="modal">
                <MyModalContents />
            </Modal>
        </View>
    }
}
```

### Modal

```js
class Modal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            visible: false,
        }

    }
    show() {
        this.setState({visible: true});
    }
    close(){
        this.setState({visible: false});
    }
    render(){
        return <View style={{opacity: this.state.visible ? 1 : 0}} pointerEvents={this.state.visible ? 'auto' : 'none'}>

            {/* can pass props with second argument */}
            {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                parent: this.props.parent,
                modal: this
            })}
        </View>
    }
}
```

### MyModalContents

```js
class MyModalContents extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

    }
    _updateModalState() {

        const self = this;

        // will update the "Main" component state as props are passed through modal
        this.props.parent.setState({myText: 'Updated Text!'}, () => {

            self.props.modal.close();

        });

    }
    render(){
        return <View>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._updateModalState}>
                <Text> Update Modal State </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I ve got the point and found this which is a more suitable approach for react-native: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082498/react-native-child-parent-communication